# How can I combine several data in one vector to one data with R?

Tags: r

I have a vector which have strings inside of itself.

So it Looks like this

> AB[1:10]

```
[1] "The most important thing we've learned,"
[2] "So far as children are concerned,"
[3] "Is never, NEVER, NEVER let"
...
[10] "Them near your television set --"
```

But I want to all things in one basket.
I mean

> AB

```
[1] "The most important thing we've learned, So far as children are concerned, Is never, NEVER, NEVER let Them near your television set --"
```

When I use mode function to identify my variable AB, then it returns

> mode(AB)

```
[1] "character"
```

I really need your help.

Thank you for reading this. Sincerely,

Comment: `toString(AB)` or `paste(AB, collapse = ",")`

Comment: Really thank you for your help. I solved it with your help. Thanks.